# CSS body properties need the !imporant keyword to take place

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Project Web</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</body>

<link href="index_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

and the following CSS (in the index_style.css file):

```
body {
  background-color: black !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

As you can tell, the "background-color" and "color" properties take place only when they are followed by the !important keyword. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include your `index_style.css` link **after** your bootstrap code.

This is because your styles are amended by whatever bootstrap styles are.

You want to set defaults by first including bootstrap, than update these attributes with your own code.

This is called Precedence in CSS and it's super useful once you understand how it works.

[Precedence in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/precedence-css-order-css-matters/)

I can see another issue in order of your scripts, your correct order should be:

```
<!-- put these inside a <head></head> -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="index_style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- put this just before closing </body> tag -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Because the styles are cascading, so the browser takes either the more detailed, or the last Style rule and applies it. So if you include your css after bootstrap, your styles are the last one the browser finds, so they overwrite the bootstrap rules.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you're loading bootsrap's CSS **after** your own CSS. When you do, Bootstrap's CSS overrides all your `body` declerations and only `!important` causes them to be applied over bootstrap's declerations.

To fix this, load the CSS files in this order:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="index_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Right order of calling css files is issue here, please use your custom styles after bootstrap styles to fix this and to overwrite styles for other components too, so right order will be as below:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="index_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, your CSS is getting overridden. When including external CSS files add your own CSS file after the external files.

The rule of overriding also applies inside the CSS file.

```
 body {
  background-color: black; 
  color: white !important;
  background-color: red;
 }
```

The background color of the following is gonna be red because background-color is declared last.

Whatever is declared last will override whats declared before it. Keep this in mind, as it will save you time in the future and it makes using  !important unnecessary